# node.js express Session refresh on ie 10

Tags: node.js

help me! when I get sessionid in ie10 then sessionid refresh
code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
sid=req.sessionID;
console.log(sid);
})
```

when I debug by line: console.log(req.headers)

1. ie10:

> ```
> { accept: 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
> referer: 'xxx',
> 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
> 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)',
> 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
> host: 'xxx',
> dnt: '1',
> connection: 'Keep-Alive' }
> ```

1. firefox:

> ```
> {host: 'xxx',
> 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0',
> accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
> 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
> 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
> referer: 'xxx',
> cookie:'express.sid=s%3ApAklVxSVjtj33ODVAoTSFSSH.KUaDHAs4%2F%2BqKpSzZTmaNMwVK8w0pmqflsWBbZVnTe1M',
> connection: 'keep-alive' }
> ```

param cookie not found in ie10

Comment: Are cookies enabled on your browser?